How to Connect Synapse Notebook to SQL Serverless Pool
I'm working with Azure Synapse Analytics and I need to connect my Synapse Notebook to my SQL Serverless Pool to drop and create views directly within the notebook. However, when I try to run the DROP VIEW command within the notebook without explicitly establishing a connection, I receive the following error:
[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND]
Even though the view does exist, I cannot seem to execute the command successfully.
I have tried searching for solutions on how to establish the connection within the notebook but couldn't find any relevant information.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Could you please provide sample code which you have used to connect serverless SQL pool?

Please check which Driver you are using to connect.
your_connection_string = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<your-synapse-workspace>.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;Database=<database-name>;Uid=<username>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"

server = '<serverName>-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net'
Port = 1433
Database = "db"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{server}:{Port};databaseName={Database};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"

if you provide your sample code we can discuss better.
